# Props and Templates

Tags: nativescript-vue

I'm just creating my first custom component, and I'm really struggling with the basics. My component:

```
<template>
<StackLayout>
  <Label :text="title" />
  <Label :text="slate.description" />
</StackLayout>
</template>

<script>
var slate;
export default {
name: "SlateComponent",

props:
  ['slate', 'title'],

data() {
  return {
    slate: slate,    
  };
},    
}
</script>
```

This component is to be updated regularly, and occupy a good chunk of the app home page:

```
<template>
<Page class="Page" actionBarHidden="true" backgroundSpanUnderStatusBar="true" >
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout row="0">
      ...
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout row="1">
          <SlateComponent :title="title" :slate="slate" />
    </StackLayout>
...
</Page>
</template>

<script>
...
```

```
    import SlateComponent from "./SlateComponent";

    var slateTitle;
    var title;
    var gameSlates;
    var currentSlate;
    var slate;

    data() {
            return {
                events: events,
                title: title,
                slate: slate,
            };
        },


    async created() {
            this.gameSlates = await getGameSlates();
            this.currentSlate = this.gameSlates[2];
            this.title = this.currentSlate.description;
            console.info("The title is: " + this.title);
            this.slate = this.currentSlate;
    }
    };
```

Result: No matter what I do, no props object passes to the component.

If I comment out the 
      
the app compiles and runs fine, logs currentSlate or its property,  `description` and displays the component, including `title`.

But, when I include that line, it blows up, with the error: `slate` is undefined.

(I know that

```
props:
      ['slate', 'title'],
```

is not proper according to the style guide. But I couldn't get the preferred format to work either.)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing props anywhere outside of the template, `this` is required

```
 data() {
      return {
        slate: slate,    
      };
    }
```

Should be

```
data() {
  return {
    slate: this.slate   
  };
},
```

Comment: Thank you! Think I tried that, but may have been messed up by earlier bar name. If bar was currentSlate, what would template use?

Comment: @EdJones I'm not sure what your asking? But in addition to my answer, vars like (var slateTitle;) should not be needed very often in Vue. Your vars should be defined in the data function

Comment: Sorry, was typing on phone without my glasses. Yes, I meant var.

Comment: I've never seen any explanation of the data function in NativeScript-vue with single-file components. Huge gap in the basic documentation/ecosystem. It's been random trials for a couple months now.

Comment: That's because it's assumed that you have basic knowledge of Vue.js. If you are planning to spend some time developing in NativeScript-Vue, I strongly suggest learning Vue first.

Comment: @TomG I’ve noticed that, but it makes no sense. NativeScript-Vue single-page is a beautiful, elegant approach, years in the making, and on its face extremely accessible to new young developers. (After they learn the ins and outs of JavaScript.) Yet then the community seems to say, “Hey, use our framework, but first go learn some other, more confusing syntax. Then come back and use our simple, elegant syntax and framework.

Comment: What you're referring to is Vue itself. Comparing a plain NativeScript project and a Vue project might give you a better understanding of both frameworks.